# Get table/rows from database then insert into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, dom

I'd rather not use this long code. I want to retrieve table/rows from database and insert into JavaScript to create a table in HTML.

This is what it looks like so far and I'd like to keep the design if possible:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDUqk.jpg

```js
var time = 10
var wrongs = 0;
var wrongs2 = 0;
var next = 0;
var right = 0;
var right2 = 0;
function timer(){ 
 if(!time<1){
 time = time - 1
 refresh()
 }else{
  randquestion()
 wrongs = wrongs + 1
 wrongs2 = wrongs2 + 1
 time = time + 10
 result.innerHTML = "<b>Failed!</b>"
 wrong.innerHTML = "<b>Wrong | "+wrongs+"</b>"
 }
}

function start(){
 if (next==0){
  next = 1;
 }
if (next==1){ 
 refresh()
 enable()
 randquestion()
 update = setInterval("timer()",1000)
 next = 2;
 }
}
function stop(){
 next = 0;
if (next == 0){ 
 randquestion()
 disable()
 time = 10
 wrongs = 0
 right = 0
 refresh()
 window.clearInterval(update);
 }
}
function changepw(){
 window.location.href = 'newpw.php';
}
function logout(){
 window.location.href = 'logout.php?logout';
}


var sel
var questions
var namev
var answers
var eng
function onenter(e){
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
 questions = document.getElementById("questionsbox").innerHTML;
 answers = document.getElementById("answer").value;
 time = 10
 refresh()
 if (answers==namev){
  right = right + 1
  right2 = right2 + 1
  test.innerHTML = "<b>Correct Answer | "+namev+"</b>"
  randquestion()
  }else{
   wrongs = wrongs + 1
   wrongs2 = wrongs2 + 1
   test.innerHTML = "<b>Correct Answer | "+namev+"</b>"
   randquestion()
  }
 }
}

function findquestion(){
 if (questions=="日本語"){
  te="japan"
 }
}
function disable(){
 document.getElementById('answer').disabled = true;
}
function enable(){
 document.getElementById('answer').disabled = false;
}

function randquestion(){
 sel = Math.floor(Math.random() * 17) + 1  
 document.getElementById("answer").value = '';
 if (sel==1){
  namev = "nihongo" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>日本語</b>"
 }
 if (sel==2){
  namev = "kyou" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>今日</b>"
 }
 if (sel==3){
  namev = "iku" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>行く</b>"
 }
 if (sel==4){
  namev = "ohayou" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>おはよう</b>"
 }
 if (sel==5){
  namev = "asa" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
 }
 if (sel==6){
  namev = "nihon" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>日本</b>"
 }
 if (sel==7){
  namev = "anata" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>貴方</b>"
 }
 if (sel==8){
  namev = "kore" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>之</b>"
 }
 if (sel==9){
  namev = "sore" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>其</b>"
 }
 if (sel==10){
  namev = "are" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>荒</b>"
 }
 if (sel==11){
  namev = "shigoto" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>仕事</b>"
 }
 if (sel==12){
  namev = "nomu" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>飲む</b>"
 }
 if (sel==13){
  namev = "naru" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>成る</b>"
 }
 if (sel==14){
  namev = "sekai" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>世界</b>"
 }
 if (sel==15){
  namev = "mizu" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>水</b>"
 }
 if (sel==16){
  namev = "kenkyou" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>研究</b>"
 }
 if (sel==17){
  namev = "sakura" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>桜</b>"
 }
 if (sel==18){
  namev = "sensei" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>先生</b>"
 }
 if (sel==19){
  namev = "kawaii" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>かわいい</b>"
 }
 if (sel==20){
  namev = "yatta" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>やった</b>"
 }
 if (sel==21){
  namev = "" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b></b>"
 }
 if (sel==22){
  namev = "" 
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b></b>"
 }
}
function refresh(){
 result.innerHTML = "<b>Timer | "+time+"</b>"
 wrong.innerHTML = "<b>Wrong | "+wrongs+"</b>"
 wrong2.innerHTML = "<b>Total Wrong | "+wrongs2+"</b>"
 correct.innerHTML = "<b>Correct | "+right+"</b>"
 correct2.innerHTML = "<b>Total Correct | "+right2+"</b>"
}
function table(){
  r1c1.innerHTML = "<b>nihongo</b>"
  r1c2.innerHTML = "<b>日本語</b>"
  r1c3.innerHTML = "<b>japanese</b>"
  
  r2c1.innerHTML = "<b>kyou</b>"
  r2c2.innerHTML = "<b>今日</b>"
  r2c3.innerHTML = "<b>today</b>"
  
  r3c1.innerHTML = "<b>iku</b>"
  r3c2.innerHTML = "<b>行く</b>"
  r3c3.innerHTML = "<b>go</b>"
  
  r4c1.innerHTML = "<b>ohayou</b>"
  r4c2.innerHTML = "<b>おはよう</b>"
  r4c3.innerHTML = "<b>good morning</b>"
  
  r5c1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  r5c2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  r5c3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  
  r6c1.innerHTML = "<b>nihon</b>"
  r6c2.innerHTML = "<b>日本</b>"
  r6c3.innerHTML = "<b>japan</b>"
  
  r7c1.innerHTML = "<b>anata</b>"
  r7c2.innerHTML = "<b>貴方</b>"
  r7c3.innerHTML = "<b>you</b>"
  
  r8c1.innerHTML = "<b>kore</b>"
  r8c2.innerHTML = "<b>之</b>"
  r8c3.innerHTML = "<b>this</b>"
  
  r9c1.innerHTML = "<b>sore</b>"
  r9c2.innerHTML = "<b>其</b>"
  r9c3.innerHTML = "<b>there</b>"
  
  r10c1.innerHTML = "<b>are</b>"
  r10c2.innerHTML = "<b>荒</b>"
  r10c3.innerHTML = "<b>that</b>"
  
  r11c1.innerHTML = "<b>shigoto</b>"
  r11c2.innerHTML = "<b>仕事</b>"
  r11c3.innerHTML = "<b>work</b>"
  
  r12c1.innerHTML = "<b>nomu</b>"
  r12c2.innerHTML = "<b>飲む</b>"
  r12c3.innerHTML = "<b>to drink</b>"
  
  r13c1.innerHTML = "<b>naru</b>"
  r13c2.innerHTML = "<b>成る</b>"
  r13c3.innerHTML = "<b>to become</b>"
  
  r14c1.innerHTML = "<b>sekai</b>"
  r14c2.innerHTML = "<b>世界</b>"
  r14c3.innerHTML = "<b>world</b>"
  
  r15c1.innerHTML = "<b>mizu</b>"
  r15c2.innerHTML = "<b>水</b>"
  r15c3.innerHTML = "<b>water</b>"
  
  r16c1.innerHTML = "<b>kenkyou</b>"
  r16c2.innerHTML = "<b>研究</b>"
  r16c3.innerHTML = "<b>study</b>"
  
  r17c1.innerHTML = "<b>sakura</b>"
  r17c2.innerHTML = "<b>桜</b>"
  r17c3.innerHTML = "<b>cherry blossom</b>"
  
  r18c1.innerHTML = "<b>sensei</b>"
  r18c2.innerHTML = "<b>先生</b>"
  r18c3.innerHTML = "<b>teacher</b>"
  
  r19c1.innerHTML = "<b>kawaii</b>"
  r19c2.innerHTML = "<b>かわいい</b>"
  r19c3.innerHTML = "<b>cute</b>"
  
  r20c1.innerHTML = "<b>yatta</b>"
  r20c2.innerHTML = "<b>やった</b>"
  r20c3.innerHTML = "<b>hooray</b>"
  
  r21c1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  r21c2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  r21c3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  
  r22c1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  r22c2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  r22c3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  
  r23c1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  r23c2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  r23c3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  
  r24c1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  r24c2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  r24c3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  
  r25c1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  r25c2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  r25c3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  
  r26c1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  r26c2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  r26c3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  
  rc1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  rc2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  rc3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  rc3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
  
  //rc1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  //rc2.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
  //rc3.innerHTML = "<b>morning</b>"
}
```

```html
<?php

session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';


if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
}
echo $_GET['right'];
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <header>
  <title>Quiz</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/reload.js"></script>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <nav>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li><a href="home.php">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="quiz.php">Quiz</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="">Study</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/1606566483004459/"target="_blank">Facebook</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
 </header>
 

 
 <body onload="table()">
  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
     <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div onmousedown='return false;'class="panel-heading"><b><?php echo "Welcome ".$_SESSION['user']. ".<br>";?></b></div>
     <div class="panel-body">
     <div>
       <input onclick="logout()" class="l btn btn-default2" type="submit" value="Logout" />
       <input onclick="changepw()" class="l btn btn-default2" type="submit" value="Change Password" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 
  <div class="container">
  <table class="table table-default">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th> <div class="list-group-item"> Romanji</th> </div>
        <th> <div class="list-group-item"> ひらがな｜カタカナ｜漢字</th> </div>
        <th> <div class="list-group-item"> English</th> </div>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> <div  id="r1c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r1c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r1c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
      <tr>
  <td> <div  id="r2c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r2c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r2c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> <div  id="r3c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r3c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r3c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   <tr>
        <td> <div  id="r4c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r4c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r4c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   <tr>
        <td> <div  id="r5c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r5c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r5c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   <tr>
        <td> <div  id="r6c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r6c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r6c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r7c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r7c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r7c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r8c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r8c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r8c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r9c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r9c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r9c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r10c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r10c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r10c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r11c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r11c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r11c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r12c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r12c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r12c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r13c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r13c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r13c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r14c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r14c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r14c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r15c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r15c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r15c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r16c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r16c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r16c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r17c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r17c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r17c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r18c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r18c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r18c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r19c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r19c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r19c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="r20c1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r20c2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="r20c3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
   </tr><tr>
        <td> <div  id="rc1" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="rc2" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
        <td> <div  id="rc3" class="list-group-item"></td> </div>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

 
 </body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Use `else if` in `randquestion()` or better, use an array  of objects where each object store `namev` and the innerHTML.

Comment: @Tushar A `switch` is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Invalid order of tags in the table, should be `<td><div...></div></td>`.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Global Variables:** All the variables defined are *global*, which is bad practice. Avoid declaring global variables. Wrap the code in IIFE and define variables using `var` keyword.
2. **Naming Conventions:** The names of the variable should give indication of it's purpose. The names should be in camelCase format.
3. Caching: Cache the DOM element reference and use it. This will save the time to *dive* into DOM again.
4. **Missing Semicolons:** Although, this will not cause any errors since JavaScript's Automatic Semicolon Insertion(ASI) will add the semicolons, it's good practice to add them. Also, depending on ASI can cause the semicolon to add someplace where the symantic will be changes. Ex: When declaring multiple variables if we forgot a comma, the successive variables will be declared as Global.
5. **Comparison:** To compare variables use strict comparison operators(`===` and `!==`). Loose comparison will cast the operands before comparing variables which could lead into unexpected behavior.
6. **Using `else if` ladder:** For mutually exclusive conditions, use `else if`. If the condition is satisfied, the next conditions in `else if` are not executed. Or `switch` statement can also be used.
7. **Nested `for`:** Use nested `for` loops to iterate over the `<table>` and update the values of each cell.(`table()`)
8. **Appending Markup:** Instead of appending markup(*like `<b>` element in `refresh()`*), IF POSSIBLE, add the markup in the HTML and only update the text-content of the element through JavaScript. This will avoid adding multiple nested elements if the function is repeatedly called.
9. **Comparing Variables:** `!time < 1` is equivalent to `time >= 1` which is more readable and easy to understand. Also, this will save an operation(Logical Not).
10. **Using string parameter to `setInterval`:** Don't use string parameter to the `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions. You can pass the function reference as `setInterval(timer, 1000)`
11. **Un-Needed Code:** In `stop()` first `next` variable is assigned to zero and then it is compared with zero which is **always** going to evaluate as `true`. The `if` condition is not necessary there.
12. **Similar Functions:** The functions `changepw()` and `logout()` are similar. Both are redirecting to some page. This can be combined into one function `redirect(url)` accepting a parameter as redirect URL and redirect to that URL. Same is with `disable()` and `enable()` functions.
13. **Logical Error & Dead Code:** The expression `Math.floor(Math.random() * 17) + 1` will always produce value between one and seventeen. So, the code written for comparing it 18 through 22 is dead code, which can be removed safely. Or, if you want to generate the random number between one to twenty-two replace the `17` by `22` in that statement.
14. **Binding Events:** Use `addEventListener` to bind events on elements. As in the current code, no event binding code is shown, if inline binding in HTML is used, use `addEventListener` to bind events.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript

- Cache DOM references - anytime `document.getElementById()` is called multiple times, it is better to store that reference in a variable (or [const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) if you are supporting es-6)
- As other's have suggested, a [switch statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) can simplify the `if-else` blocks of `randquestion()`. Another technique is to use a mapping of values. For instance, ones could define an array for the names and questions:

  ```
  var namevs = ["nihongo", "kyou", "iku", ..., "yatta"];
  var questions = ["日本語", "今日", "行く", ..., "やった<"];
  ```

  Then use those values by index, as in the sample below. Notice that the value assigned to `sel` does not need to be increased after taking the floor of the random number between 0 and 17, since array index is 0-based.

  ```
  sel = Math.floor(Math.random() * 17);
  namev = namevs[sel];
  questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>" + questions[sel] + "</b>";
  ```
- The random value in `sel` will at most have a value of 17. Thus the last 6 conditional code blocks of `randquestion()` will never get executed. If those last few questions need to be accessible, then update the math for generating `sel` - if the array mappings above are used, one could utilize those:

  ```
  sel = Math.floor(Math.random() * namevs.length);
  ```
- There are lines of code in the `table()` function that reference DOM elements implicitly by *id* attribute, which do not exist in the DOM:

  ```
  r21c1.innerHTML = "<b>asa</b>"
  ```

  This leads to an error in the browser console:

  > <sub>Uncaught ReferenceError: r21c1 is not defined</sub>

#### HTML

- In the snippet HTML, jQuery version 1.12.4 is linked in the `<head>` section, then version 1.11.3 is included towards the end. It doesn't appear that either are used in your JavaScript code, just used for Bootstrap.
- The table headers and cells appear to have `<div>` tags that are not closed before the cell is closed. For example:

  > ```
  >    <th> <div class="list-group-item"> Romanji</th> </div>
  > ```

  Valid HTML would look like the following:

  ```
   <th> <div class="list-group-item"> Romanji</div>  </th>
  ```

### PHP

I see the following line:

> ```
> echo $_GET['right'];
> ```

Which would come *before* the HTML content... is that just left in for debugging purposes? It would be advisable not to echo content before the start of the HTML content.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

The moment you start doing things like the following, you got yourself a maintainability problem:

```
if (sel==4){
    namev = "ohayou" 
    questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>おはよう</b>"
}
if (sel==5){
    namev = "asa" 
    questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
}
if (sel==6){
    namev = "nihon" 
    questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>日本</b>"
}
if (sel==7){
    namev = "anata" 
    questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>貴方</b>"
}
```

What if you decide to rename `sel`? You'd have to rename it everywhere!

```
switch (sel) {
    case 4:
        namev = "ohayou" 
        questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>おはよう</b>"
        break;
    case 5:
        namev = "asa" 
        questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>朝</b>"
        break;
    case 6:
        namev = "nihon" 
        questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>日本</b>"
        break;
    case 7:
        namev = "anata" 
        questionsbox.innerHTML = "<b>貴方</b>"
        break;
}
```

Much neater! Easier to maintain, you're not needlessly repeating yourself (those `break` are more like parentheses in this regard) and it's immediately clear all those conditionals rely on the same variable. The ease of understanding your code just went up a couple of points.

Comment: I agree that `switch` will make code a bit better but there is something wrong with design if you have to put statements that long in your logic. Putting all those words in separate files would make code more readable.

Comment: This could use a an associative array in PHP or an array of strings that are sorted properly as well.